# confusion of usage of would

Tags: will-would

I have heard these type of sentences

> 1) I would like to invite Mr.Ram to the stage

---

> 2)I would like to thankyou

---

Why would is used in these sentences? Are they hypotetical ? Are the conditional, with some implicit or unstated condition?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of formal syntax, OP's examples are indeed "hypothetical", but that's not really the intended ***meaning***. In such contexts, modal verbs and subjunctives are primarily intended to "distance" the speaker from both the utterance itself, ***and the verbal interaction within which it occurs***.

That's to say, these forms are used when the speaker doesn't want to appear "personally" involved. Often the implication is that the speaker's opinions are not "worthy" of being voiced (through [false modesty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/false-modesty), genuine [deference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deference), or simply [convention](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/convention)). Thus...

> 1: (boss speaking to underling - speaks plainly / bluntly)
>    *Your plan won't work*
>    2: (Underling speaking to boss - speaks deferentially / obliquely)
>    ***If*** you **were** to ask me, I **would have to** say your plan **might** not work

I don't know if it's based in reality, but sterotypically the *Japanese* are particularly mindful of this kind of "deference to social superiors". No cultural slur is intended here obviously, but I think I could reasonably extend those examples with...

> 3: (*Japanese* underling speaking to boss - speaks *very* deferentially / obliquely)
>    *If you were to ask **this one**, **he** would have to say your plan might not work*

---

TL;DR: It would be more accurate to say OP's examples are ***deferential***, rather than ***hypothetical***.

Comment: so in restaurants if we say "I would like to have some lunch"  to waiter. It is just used to show modesty (false modesty) ? But it's underlying conditin is If you were to ask me, I would like to have some lunch. (although it is not the intended meaning). Anyway thankyou very much for your help. I almost got it. This is the best expplanatin I have seen

Comment: what about "Would you like a starter?". What is the underlying condition in this. How does this become polite way of asking?  Should I ask how does this become polite way of asking or How would this become polite way of asking?

Comment: *Would you like a starter?* is essentially the same as, say, *Would you like to follow me to your table?* It's not particularly meaningful to ask what exactly ***is*** the implied conditional, but how about ***IF you were prepared to lower yourself to respond to me your humble servant**, WOULD you accept my suggestion?* But don't take that ***too*** literally - it's more about established social conventions than true "meaning".